# Execute the 'cd' command for CMD in Go

Tags: go, exec

I want to use Go and the exec library to go to a certain path, *"c:"*, and run a .exe file.

When I run my Go code, it gives me:

> exec: "cd:/": file does not exist

Comment: It would be helpful to others if you shared your code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `cd` command is a builtin of your shell, whether bash, cmd.exe, PowerShell, or otherwise. You would not exec a `cd` command and then exec the program you want to run. Instead, you want to set the `Dir` of the `Cmd` you're going to run to the directory containing the program:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("program") // or whatever the program is
    cmd.Dir = "C:/usr/bin"         // or whatever directory it's in
    out, err := cmd.Output()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("%s", out);
    }
}
```

See the [Cmd documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd) for more information. Alternatively, you could use [os/Chdir](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Chdir) to change the working directory before running the program.

Answer (score 3):

You specify the initial working directory to run the command in the `Cmd` object:

```
cmd.Dir = "C:\\"
```

See the [documentation on the Cmd](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd) struct for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Depending if the command needs to operate in the "root" of the directory, you can use [`os.Chdir(dir)`](https://pkg.go.dev/os#Chdir) to change Go programs directory. All of the subsequent commands and paths will then be relative to the value of the `dir` provided to `os.Chdir`.