# How to change the current directory in Go

Tags: go

Unlike *[Execute the 'cd' command for CMD in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44206940/golang-execute-cd-command-for-cmd)*, I just want to really run `cd directory_location` using Go and change the current directory.

So for example,

Say I am on ~/goproject, and I run, `./main` in the terminal, I want to be at ~/goproject2 in the terminal.

I tried

```
cmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", "cd", "~/goproject2")
cmd.Run()
```

But this didn't actually change the current directory.

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Chdir

Comment: You cannot change the shell's cwd from an application.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Is there no way? Even a convoluted idea would be useful

Comment: On workaround is to source the output of the command in the shell.

Comment: That's impossible because of the chicken and egg problem. Any shell distinguishes between the "built-in" and "external" commands. The former are executed directly by the shell's process and the latter are executed as child processed. A child process cannot change any property of its parent, so external processes can't change their parent's current directory (well, almost--see below).
That's exactly why `cd` is a shell's *built-in* command, and you cannot implement it as an external command.

Comment: Well, you can resort to hacks like `ptrace(2)` on Linux to command the parent process but that would clearly violate the process separation principles.

Answer (score 43):

Usually if you need a command to run from a specific directory, you can specify that as the *Dir* property on the *Command*, for example:

```
cmd := exec.Command("myCommand", "arg1", "arg2")
cmd.Dir = "/path/to/work/dir"
cmd.Run()
```

Comment: Man you have nailed it!

Answer (score 31):

You want [`os.Chdir`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Chdir). This function will change the *application working directory*. If you need to change the *shell working directory*, your best bet is to look up how `cd` works and work back from that.

As you have discovered, you cannot use `cd` to change your current directory from inside an application, but with `os.Chdir` there is no need for it to work :)

Example usage:

```
home, _ := os.UserHomeDir()
err := os.Chdir(filepath.Join(home, "goproject2"))
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to actually change the terminal location after I run the go program. When I print the error, I see that there was no error for `os.Chdir()`. I see that error is `<nil>`.

Comment: Of course it doesn't change the terminal location. Changing the terminal location is much more complicated. You still can't use `cd`, and there is nothing in the Go standard libary to help you. Your best bet is to look at source code for `cd` itself and work backwards from there.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'll try to find a work around.

Comment: This is very useful especially when zipping files in go.